# Can't I access outer class var from inner singleton?

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin and way rusty on Java but I am trying to accomplish the instantiation of a inner Singleton object which uses a outer class variable to construct:

```kotlin
class Foo(inpoint: String) {
    val point: Path
    val bar: Bar
    object Bar {
        val content: String
        init {
            content = point.toFile().readText()
        }
    }
    init {
        point = Paths.get(inpoint)
        bar = Bar
    }
}
```

I get an error on the Singleton `Bar` init trying to get the `Foo` point (Path)

Comment: Looks impossible for `object`s so far. If `Bar` was a `class`, you could make it an `inner class` to enable access to fields of the super `class`, but that keyword is not allowed for an `object`.

Comment: @deHaar What I am trying to do is create a singleton that relies on a state (in this case the existence of a path variable, which is not known until runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `point` is a member variable of class `Foo`. Every object of this class will have its own copy of this variable. So it can only be accessed from an object of this class.

`Bar` on the other hand is a static class. It belongs to class `Foo` and not to an object of `Foo`.

If you want to access `point` inside `Bar`, you will have to put it inside `Bar` definition but then you will only have one copy of `point` throughout the program.

```kotlin
object Bar {
    private lateinit var point: Path
    private lateinit var content: String

    fun setPoint(inpoint: String) {
        point = Paths.get(inpoint)
        content = point.toFile().readText()
    }
}
```

Comment: I only do want 1 copy of point throughout the program but how do I get point (a String retrieved from the command line at runtime) into the initialization of Bar? I can remove Bar from Foo as I really only want the Bar Singleton. Foo was my hackfest to get a Singleton initialized with a run time, not compile time, value.

Comment: You can start with a nullable `Path` inside Bar and then initialize it when you receive the command line input. Or you can go with the Java style singleton pattern (using non-static fields)

Comment: Again, Kotlin newby, not sure how to accomplish that. Would you mind a simple snippet edit to your answer?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now when you get input from command line you can call `Bar.setPoint(input)` to initialize the data.

Comment: Ahhhh... wasn't aware of these modifiers!